# Create a range rule in Prolog

Tags: prolog, range, clpfd

I want to create 3 range in prolog like these:

```
if CF >70 and <80 -> range 1
if CF >81 and <90 -> range 2
if CF >91 and <100 -> range 3
```

Then I want to pass the range value to another predicate depending on the CF value. Ex: `advice(D,RANGE).`
Could someone help me??
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) we can write:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

cf_range(X,1) :- X in 71..79.
cf_range(X,2) :- X in 82..89.
cf_range(X,3) :- X in 92..99.
```

Check the boundaries again to ensure that no values fall through the cracks, like `90` does now.